# Redirect from cgi file to another cgi file in WHM

Tags: perl, cgi, cpanel, whm

I am working on WHM, I have displayed a form using CGI scripting. Now, I want to redirect to next CGI page which I have mentioned in form's action attribute. But, I am not able to do the same and getting error as follows-

```
Internal Server Error
500

No response from subprocess (/usr/local/cpanel/whostmgr/docroot/cgi/XYZ/abc.cgi): The subprocess reported error number 72,057,594,037,927,935 when it ended. The process dumped a core file.
cpsrvd Server at vps235171.vps.ovh.ca
```

I kept my both the files (form and abc.cgi) in same directory. Also, tried with the extension .pl and even without extension.

I want to redirect on next page(abc.cgi) as there is my actual buisness logic.
Someone please, help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: May /usr/local/cpanel/whostmgr/docroot/cgi/XYZ/abc.cgi has not execute permission?

Comment: I'm not sure what "WHM" is, but if I were you, I'd start by investigating what that (huge!) error code means. But we really can't be much help to you without seeing your code. Also, I'd ask you to consider why you're writing CGI programs in 2019, when there are [far better technologies available](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives).

Comment: Re "*I'd start by investigating what that (huge!) error code means*", It's `0xFF FFFF FFFF FFFF`. It looks like -1 was passed to `WEXITSTATUS` or similar, so I doubt that it's meaningful

Comment: @Dave Cross, huh, that's a list of alternatives to CGI.pm (the module), not CGI (the protocol). In fact, the some of the listed examples specifically use CGI.

Comment: @ikegami: Fair point. I guess I over-simplified. I suppose what I really mean is "switch something which isolates your code from the deployment environment".

Comment: @Dave Cross, For all you know, that's already being done.

Comment: @P N Jain, I'm not sure how much we can do. But I'm curious: 1) Where are you getting that error? 2) You talk about redirection as if it's relevant, but you haven't provided any hint as to why you think that. How do you redirect, and what happens if you simply request the next page directly?

Comment: Thank you so much everyone for your efforts. I found the solution, page actually got redirected after just mentioning in action attribute of form. But, the mistake was I forgot to mentioned content type which is very important in cgi-perl script. So, now its working fine. Thank you once again

Comment: @PNJain You should consider putting your last comment as response.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your CGI crashed. You may find more details if analyse the core file.

Each CGI is an executable file. If you execute your CGI under the same user as the server you should get the same error.

```
/usr/local/cpanel/whostmgr/docroot/cgi/XYZ/abc.cgi > abc.html
```